# SharePoint 2013 Enterprise CALs and Enterprirse Agreement semantics

Tags: sharepoint-server, licensing, cal

**Backstory:** I have a customer that has x number of SharePoint eCALS as part of their EA, and 0 Standard CALs as part of the same EA.

**The question:** Given that eCALs are additive, should their EA explicitly state the number of Standard CALs they possess, or are Standard CALs "covered" by virtue of the fact that the EA allots them x number of eCALs?

I work with a few ex-Micrososft-types that say "they are covered", but I wanted to know others' experience with EAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who issued or manages their agreement?  You should have them validate it via MS to be 100% sure.  It it's part of the CAL Suite you are covered.  If they explicitly SharePoint Enterprise not part of a package, I would hesitate to say yes.

But again - if you want an true answer, you need to get it from MS stating you are covered.

Comment: I'm having them confirm with their vendor that it has been validated recently. They said they just completed a review but that may have been internal. Since MS states they are additive, I wish they'd just act logically and enumerate them as such in EAs. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Ecal includes scal, but then again, I wouldn't trust anything anyone says here when it comes to licensing. It only matters what MS says.